# R POST/GET Issues not returning cookie

Tags: r, post, cookies, get, httr

Very strange issue. I am trying to connect to some API (inside organization) which require first to POST key & code to some url and then use that cookie to get the desired data (json).

Running the POST request returns status 200 which is good - but no cookie is returned. 
Running the same request in Firefox using "httprequester" returns a cookie as expected and works fine.

```
url<-"https://some_url"
login <- list(
  Key="some_key",
  Code="some_code"
)

try_temp<-POST(url = url,body=login,encode="form",verbose())
```

Result is:

```
-> POST /api/Service/Login HTTP/1.1
-> Host: **************
-> User-Agent: libcurl/7.53.1 r-curl/2.5 httr/1.2.1
-> Accept-Encoding: gzip, deflate
-> Accept: application/json, text/xml, application/xml, */*
-> Content-Type: application/x-www-form-urlencoded
-> Content-Length: 43
-> 
>> Key=*****&Code=*******

<- HTTP/1.1 200 OK
<- Content-Type: text/html; charset="utf-8"
<- Content-Length: 6908
<- Connection: Close
<-
```

Thing is, that the same request works when down in browser. 
GET request (after I know the cookie, I use GET in httr passing the cookie i've got. I get the same log as above.
BTW When instead of GET i use BROWSE - R opens the default browser and i see the expected data returned.

I suspect that some of the settings for R are not the same as for Firefox (or any other browser). We don't use PROXY but rather automatic configuration script.

Tnx

Comment: Did you try `cookies(try_temp)` or `content(try_temp)$cookies` ?

Comment: @ricoderks Yes, it simply returns empty string.

Comment: Maybe you can use  `user_agent` to modify the User-agent in order to idenrify yoursrlf as a browser.

Comment: Tried that too, even different browsers, versions. It's probably the verification onsite is problematic - otherwise I wouldn't get code 200 which is success

Comment: Hmmm, unfortunately I'am not really helpfull. One last thing to maybe narrow down the problem a bit. Did you try it with curl from the command line to see if the problem is in curl or the R package?

Comment: Curl also doesn't work

Comment: Few years ago I also had a problem with curl and a post form. It turned out to be a redirect problem. I can't remember exactly how I solved it. For curl there is a parameter thay it shoild follow redirects. Maybe this helps a bit.